# Shared assembly attributes during TFS builds

Tags: git, version-control, shared-libraries, .net-assembly, projects-and-solutions

I'm looking for an elegant solution—if there is one—to the problem of linking to an out-of-project shared assembly attributes file and then pushing that project to TFS for a build.

I'm in the process of converting all of my local solutions and projects to source control (it's been a long time coming) and publishing the shared code as NuGet packages. My new design enforces one solution per package, with each solution containing one main project and one test project. In other words, one working assembly per solution.

Previously, when working from my local machine only, I'd reference several of these 'library' projects in a given solution, so the linked shared file solution worked well, e.g. `<Assembly: AssemblyCompany("My Company")>`. Consistency among these attributes is very important, for registry key naming, etc.

But now sending these projects to the build server presents a problem; the linked file doesn't exist on the server and so the build naturally fails.

I'm trying to avoid the tedium and human error that comes with manually editing the `AssemblyInfo.vb` file for each and every new project I create. Linking was perfect, but it now no longer works. (The code also needs to run locally during dev, so tuning it up in a build step isn't an option.)

I'm rather new to source control and build architectures; what are good folks out there doing to address this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be pretty easy.

Here's how:

1. In each project, remove any existing link to `ServiceInfo.vb`
2. Insert this command into each project's pre-build event

   > copy /y $(SolutionDir)..\ServiceInfo.vb $(SolutionDir)ServiceInfo.vb
3. Build each project to copy the file
4. In each project, link to `$(SolutionDir)ServiceInfo.vb`

Depending on your code, the build in Step #3 may fail because it can't find `ServiceInfo.vb`. No problem, just build it again after you've created the link in Step #4.

This will ensure that `ServiceInfo.vb` is included in your Git publish to TFS and that your build step on the server will succeed.

Answer (score 0):

When building a project (in current repo), all the assemblies which the project referred should be found.

Since some of the assemblies are out of current repo (managed in another/library repo), and while the library repo has no relations with the current repo, so you will miss the assemblies of the library repo when building the project.

In order to get the assemblies from the library repo, you should “add relations” between the current repo and the library repo. There are two ways usually be used: [**submodules**](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) and [**subtree**](https://www.atlassian.com/blog/git/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree).

#### Option 1: treat library repo as a submodule for the current repo

The main repo can get the features from submodule repo, so the references of the library repo can be used when building the project from main repo. The commands used as below:

```
#In local current repo
git submodule add <URL for the library repo>
#change the reference path correspondingly
git add .
git commit -m 'add the library repo as submodule'
git push
```

Now build the project can find the assemblies from the library repo.

#### Option 2: treat the branch from library repo as a subtree for the current repo

Assume the assemblies managed in the `master` branch of the library repo, so you can add the master branch from library repo to the current repo:

```
# In local current repo
git subtree add --prefix=library <URL for the library repo> master
# change the reference path correspondingly
git add .
git commit -m 'add library master branch as subtree'
git push
```

Now the project can also be built successful.

Comment: Thank you, but these are linked files, not referenced assemblies. For example, I have a file `ServiceInfo.vb` two folder levels up from the project that links to it. A local build includes the file, because it exists in the location that the project expects it to be. The server build, however, fails—because the linked file is outside of both the local and remote repositories. The linked file is not in any repository—it simply sits outside of the project folder hierarchy. Do your suggestions still apply?

Comment: Also: does the Visual Studio 2017 UI support management of these submodule and subtree concepts?

Comment: Yes, you should add the repo which the original files located. Such as the file `ServiceInfo.vb` is located in a different repo, you should add the repo as the submodule/subtree for the current repo which your project located. So that when you build by VSTS, the linked files can be found. And to add submodule/subtree, you should use command line instead.

Comment: This doesn't sound like it's going to work. The project that links to the file looks for it at a relative path: `..\..\..\ServiceInfo.vb`. The subtree will see the file in the same local folder: `.\ServiceInfo.vb`. The build will still fail when everything gets to the server. Also, command-line will slow me down terribly. I'm hoping for an automated solution if at all possible.

Comment: Please check the linked paths are correct, or you can link the files again in the submodule/subtree. If you are using submodule, please select **checkout submodules** from Get sources step in VSTS build definition.

Comment: I'm afraid you've lost me, Marina :-)

Comment: You can try step by step, any step has problems, please feel free to let me know :)

Comment: OK, will do—thanks for your offer. In the meantime, an idea has occurred to me. I could write a small console app to parse the `AssemblyInfo.vb` file and insert the necessary entries, and run it as a pre-build command on my local machine. This way I can count on the correct info existing on the local machine, and naturally it will make it through the build on TFS. As long as I do a local build before the first push, I should be OK. No more linked files at all. What do you think?

Comment: Sounds ok but I never tested with this way. You can have a try.

Comment: I'll try it your way first. Tomorrow.

Comment: Marina, pardon me—I've had fires to put out since we talked about this, and so I haven't had a chance to work on it. To your knowledge, will this construct require me to drop to the command line for every commit/merge/sync cycle? If so, it's a deal-killer for sure. I've been reading [this](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules), and it strikes me as designing a car with seven wheels in order to be able to turn a corner, at least in this case. There's GOT to be an easier way to solve this simple problem. T4 calling a PowerShell script is starting to look attractive. Your opinion?

Comment: "If the technological context allows for packaging and formal dependency management, you should absolutely go this route." Link: https://medium.com/@porteneuve/mastering-git-submodules-34c65e940407